# gsoap onvif server, информирование о событии

Tags: c++, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, soap, onvif

Всем привет. К сожалению, в этой теме довольно слаб, по-этому даже трудно правильно составить вопрос.
Суть проблемы.
На c++ посредством gsoap реализован минимальный сервер по протоколам Onvif. Имеется сервсис DeviceBinding и  PullPointSubscriptionBinding.
В целом все работает: к серверу можно подключиться, он предоставляет базовую информацию о девайсе и реализован механизм подписки (Subscribe). Однако по документации Onvif и информации из интернета, я так и не смог понять, каким образом (с помощью реализации какой из функций сервиса PullPointSubscriptionBinding или каких механизмов soap) я должен отправить клиенту (подписчику) информацию о произошедшем событии. Интересует не реализация, а сам механизм, позволяющий отправить клиенту нужное сообщение, так как стандартного механизма запрос-ответ в этом случае нет.

Схема, которую я пытаюсь реализовать:
[image: Схема, которую я пытаюсь реализовать]